# Columns missing on Objects from DACPAC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, intellisense, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am using Visual Studio 2022 for developments in a database project (SSDT).

I have referenced multiple DACPAC files from all reqired databases from our MS SQL Servers from our organization network. The databases are from different MS SQL Server versions: 2008R2 (is also my target database), 2012, 2016 and a 2019, but I think this does not matter.

After referencing a DACPAC file I can see the Objects under my project node in the SQL Server  Object Explorer in VS. There I noticed, that the tables do not display the columns.
If I try to expand the columns node, no child nodes are displayed.

I think thats the reason why IntelliSense does not work on those objects. This makes it quite diffticult to code. Now I've to lookup the table schema to get the requiered column names etc. on the connected database. So this costs much of my time.

What I've checked so far, is that it makes no difference, if the database from the DACPAC is used with a an SQLCMD Variable for SQL Server (Other Server as my target) as I am using also databases from the current target server.

For tables I've created within my SSDT Project everythink seem to work correctly. So IntelliSense might be enabled correctly in the VS options.

Any idea what could cause the missing column/index names?

[image: Edit: Attached Screenshot from my SQL Server Object Explorer in VisualStudio 2022. The Icon vanishes after trying to expand the columns]

Comment: Could you please offer more screenshots to clarify the situation you encountered?